# For Silverlight web resources should we place xap or HTML on entity form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Normally we get two choices in case of Silverlight solutions. We can place either xap or html web resource on the entity form. I am not sure which approach is better. I found in many cases both work. MSDN example suggests to use html but I also found examples on various websites using directly xap.

Recently I found a particular case that `Xrm.Page.Data` works in case of xap but not in case of html. So I am again wondering which approach is better. What are the advantages of using one over the other.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main distinct difference I've found is that by embedding a Xap file straight into the form it has direct access to the `Xrm` property and can access form fields much easier.

If this was in a web resource, you either need to have javascript in the web resource such as

`var Xrm = window.parent.Xrm`

Which will set an `Xrm` variable in your Html resource to the `Xrm` property on the form and you can then pull it into your silverlight application to get at fields and properties.

The main difference is to do with where you want to embed your silverlight web resource. I wanted to put mine that i'm currently working on in the left hand nav on the form as its own individual page. This required editing the form adding a new Nav item but this only allows adding of a HTML web resource, so I had to embed my Silverlight App in this to get it to display.

So in summary, the advantage of direct embedding is for access form properties. But in terms of usage it depends on what it is your trying to achieve.